# SSRS Report matrix (with left join)

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report that uses a matrix to pivot the data.  The underlying query has a left join to bring back agents that have never placed a brochure order.

The TSQL returns the following:

```
ABTA    OutletName  PlacedOrder Group   SubGroup    BrochureTitle   Quantity
456789  Bobs Travel No  Group 1 Sub Grouper NULL    NULL
123456  Rays Travel Yes Group 1 Sub Grouper Wonderful Rhodes    20
123456  Rays Travel Yes Group 1 Sub Grouper Amazing Corfu   15
123456  Rays Travel Yes Group 1 Sub Grouper Exotic Burma    22
123456  Rays Travel Yes Group 1 Sub Grouper Tantalising Tanzania    8
```

As you can see Bobs Travel has never placed an order.

When this query is called in SSRS, Bobs Travel is not displayed and within the column groups an empty column appears.

Is there a way to get this working in SSRS?  I did consider a dynamic tsql pivot statement (pivot columns are not static) and then using a table, but if there is a simpler way in SSRS, then any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the NULL values by meaning strings like `No Data` in your query. If that doesn't work explain How you set the matrix.

Comment: Alejandro, I have tried that and nothing has changed.  For the Matrix, I placed ABTA, OutletName, Group, SubGroup and PlacedOrder as rows.  BorchureTitle as the Column with SUM(Quantity).  I did nothing else other than that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted what was going wrong:

Firstly it was putting the second row (Bobs Travel) on a new page.  After a long day I didn't spot multiple pages and thought it was displaying that row at all.

Secondly, I got rid of the "Null" part of the pivot where no orders have been placed, by placing this in the visibility in the column groups:

=IIF(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value,"BrochureTitle")), true, false)